# Images are not displayed (html)

Tags: html, image

I want to show three times the same picture but it won't work.

I know it isn't really hard to make but I don't know where the problem is. ._.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ul>
<div style="" align="center">

<img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="1">
<img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="2">
<img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="3">

</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your `img` directory is in the same directory than the html page?

Comment: yes, it is the same directory

Comment: You have another problem different as this. If you have `/index.html | /img/logo.jpg` it works. Maybe a permission problem, read forbidden in your server, or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you used the 'ul' tag, in this code there is no need of ul tag.
From the code the possible issue i found is the wrong image path your give. otherwise it should display the image correctly. please check your src path.

```
 <div style="" align="center">
 <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="1">
 <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="2">
 <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="3">

 </div>
```

is enough give the full image url

Comment: To the downvoter: this answer maybe is not complete, but he is right because an structure like `<ul><div><img>` it's totally incoherent. To avoid the -1 punctuation I've upvote this answer.

Comment: And please, when people downvote, leave an explanation why downvote was.

Comment: Yes, I don't need the 'ul' tag thats true.
I found the problem... I did a '/' in front of the img path... 

Thank you very much :)